# Using regex in python to extract emails

Tags: python, regex

I wrote the below program to use it for extracting emails that ends with '@aun.edu.ng' in the file 'on_campus.txt' using the regex character asterix. But when I run it, it seems to take the asterix as a string as well.

```
import re

def aun_mails():
    mail_file = open('on_campus.txt')
    for m in mail_file:
        m = m.strip()
        if re.search('*@aun.edu.ng', m):

            print m
```

aun_mails()

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you want, but you probably want `\S*@aun\.edu\.ng` as your regex. Also, `.` matches any character, not a dot specifically, you should use `\.` instead.

Comment: Example of the emails you have and what is/isn't being correctly matched would help.

Comment: Note that `*` is a quantifier. It has to used quantifying a character, character class or any other regex substructures.

Comment: if you have one email per line, you can simply check `if '@aun.edu.ng' in m:`

Comment: What do you mean by "it seems to take the asterisk as a string as well"? What asterisk? There's no asterisk (*) in your code. How is it taken as a string?

Comment: sorry @RenéPijl , I missed the asterisk. I edited it.

Comment: The main challenge I'm is that, the email is not stored per line, it is just a random text file containing lots of emails. Below is some part of the file:            david.aboderin@aun.edu.ng>, David Millar-Jaja <david.millar-jaja@aun.edu.ng>, David Okezie <david.okezie@aun.edu.ng>, Destiny Enabulele <destiny.enabulele@aun.edu.ng>, Djamal Belko Boly <djamal.boly@aun.edu.ng>, Emmanuel Oluwagbadebo Segun-Lean <emmanuel.segunlean@aun.edu.ng>

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be able to accomplish what you want without the `re` module.
Take a look at the following example:

```
myString = "Blah blah email blah sent by: some.name@aun.edu.ng"
isEmail = myString.endswith('aun.edu.ng') # isEmail will be True in this case

if isEmail == True:
    print myString # or print(myString for python 3.x)
```